# Variable name with % symbol

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, lm, predict

I'm working with a database where I can't change the variable names by company decision.

One of the variables is named as follows:

```
%Variable
```

I fit a model (`lm object`) and this variable is included.

Now I want to use the `predict()` function and I need to create a dataframe using this same name in one of the columns to be able to predict values. I'm doing the following:

```
new_x <- data.frame(X1 = 1, X2 = 0, X3 = 0, X4= 1, X5 = 0.765, `%VARIABLE` = 16.1)

predict(object = model4, newdata = new_x, level = 0.95, interval = 'confidence')
```

However, the new_x `dataframe` has the last column named as `X.VARIABLE` and not as %VARIABLE.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `names()` works.

```
names(new_x)[6] <- "%VARIABLE"

new_x

  X1 X2 X3 X4    X5 %VARIABLE
1  1  0  0  1 0.765      16.1
```